# Can someone explain why this function asks for input three times in python?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

```
def choose():
decision = input( 'Do you ' + colored('run', ('blue')) + ' or ' +
                  colored('attack?', ('blue')) )
return decision
```

`while choose():
if choose() == "attack":
etc.
elif choose() == "run":
etc.`

The interpreter then asks for the input and after it is inputted it asks again, and again, then the program proceeds normally. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: You're calling `choose()` 3 times in that bottom code, and every time you call it it will ask for input. Call it once, save the result, then use that.

Comment: *"how can I fix it?"* - call it only once and store the return value

Comment: Please accept the below answer if it fixed the problem for you. If a questions resolved, it should be marked as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the input routine only once and save the response.
Check that saved value repeatedly, rather than going back to your user each time.

```
choice = choose()
while choice:
    if choice == "attack":
        etc.
    elif choice == "run":
        etc.
    ...
    choice = choose()
```

Comment: When I do this the code runs forever. I want it to run once and the  ask for input again.

Comment: Then you add another call at the bottom of the loop.  See my update.

Comment: Great to hear.  Remember to up-vote useful things and pick a best answer; this helps you grow in the Stack Overflow community, and allows SO to properly archive the question.